# Rails + Show Dynamic content with backbone.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js

I'm making an API call using backbone model that returns JSON with list of posts.

Each post is dynamic as it can be
1. **liked** or **unliked**
2. **commented** or **not commented**
3. Shared with **Public** or **private** or **a group**

Now in my backbone template while displaying the posts, I'm doing a **if else** conditions to display the dynamic content.

```
<% if(jsonresponse["like"] == true){ *>
  <a href="/posts/1/like">Like</a>
<%} else %>
  <a href="/posts/1/like">Unlike</a>
<% } %>

<% if(jsonresponse.target == 'public'){ *>
  <a href="#">Public</a>
<%} else if(jsonresponse.target == 'private'){%>
  <a href="#">Private</a>
<% } else if(jsonresponse.target == 'groups'){%>
  <a href="#"><%= post.target.shared[0].displayName %></a>
<% } %>
```

Is this how we should display dynamic content?
Checking conditions in a template is the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it looks a bit ugly but there isn't anything wrong with it. Maybe you could split up your view into two (like/unlike ... public/private/groups) so that when user clicks on like/unlike you only render the above view.

In Handlebars, which I use, we tend to write helpers functions which abstracts these if/else and makes the view all clean. That's one option but it's a bit overkill if you only have this one situation

Comment: I was just wondering if there was a better way. Now i can code happily .. Thanks :)